# How to simplify $\cos\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)$ bases on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

First, I will introduce two identities:

1. $$\cos\left(z\right)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
2. $$\arctan\left(z\right)=\frac{i}{2}\left(\ln\left(1-iz\right)-\ln\left(1+iz\right)\right)=\frac{-1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right)$$

Now we will try to simplify the $\cos\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)$:

1. $$\cos\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{e^{i\frac{-1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)}+e^{-i\frac{-1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}}+\sqrt{\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+ix\right)\left(1+ix\right)}{\left(1-ix\right)\left(1+ix\right)}}+\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-ix\right)\left(1-ix\right)}{\left(1+ix\right)\left(1-ix\right)}}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(ix+1\right)^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}+\sqrt{\frac{\left(ix-1\right)^{2}}{1+x^{2}}}}{2}$$
2. The square root extraction operation can give two possible values, we take this into account and therefore introduce two additional variables: $$\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k_{0}}\left(ix+1\right)+\left(-1\right)^{k_{1}}\left(ix-1\right)}{2\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$$, where $k_0 ∈ [0,1] $ and $k_1 ∈ [0,1]$.
3. The research of different values of variables $k_0$ and $k_1$ will lead to a two fundamentally different version:
   $$[\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}},\frac{\pm ix}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}]$$

**Q:** What intuition underlies the choice? How to mathematically justify the choice of either the first version or the second? What are the reasons for having the second option, which is very similar to the simplified version of the $\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)$?

Comment: Try a more careful accounting of the branches of the $\ln$ and $\sqrt$ functions. This will determine the values of $k_0$ and $k_1$.

Comment: For real $x$, the solution is clearly $\cos\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ while $\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: @Henry I agree, most math textbooks include these formulas. My question attempts to derive these formulas

Answer (score 5):

**Sketch for a solution**: for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ you have that $\arctan x$ is the angle of the right-angled triangle with bottom side of length one and perpendicular side of height $x$, therefore the hypotenuse have length $h=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Now: the cosine of $\arctan x$ is the bottom side of a proportional right-angled triangle who hypotenuse have length one, therefore $\cos (\arctan x)=\frac1{h}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Finally, as the function cosine is analytic then $\cos (\arctan z)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$ in the set where $\arctan $ is also analytic, so you just need to study the behavior of the function $\arctan z$, for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, to see where the previous equality holds and where it changes. Without further study I guess that the identity $\cos (\arctan z)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$ holds for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ as far as you use the principal branch of the argument function to define the branch of the square root function.

Comment: Thanks! I omitted to mention that the Pythagorean theorem should not be used, since this question arose after trying to derive the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: @PavelDev the Pythagoream theorem is implicit in the definition of $|z|$, as $|z|^2=|\operatorname{Re}(z)|^2+|\operatorname{Im}(z)|^2$, this imply that if $w=irz$ for some $r\in \mathbb{R}$ then $|z+w|^2=|z|^2+|w|^2$ (the Pythagorean theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify $\cos (2 \arctan (x))$, noting that $e^{ \pm i \arctan(x)}$ has the same phase as $1 \pm ix$:

$$\cos (2 \arctan (x )) = \Re \left \{ \frac{e^{i \arctan(x)}}{e^{- i \arctan (x)}} \right \} = \Re \left\{ \frac{1 + ix}{1 - ix} \right \} = \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2}$$

From here onwards, you are free to use half angle formulae to your hearts content.

$$\cos (\arctan x)= \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos (2\arctan (x))}{2}}$$
$$\sin(\arctan x)= \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos (2\arctan (x))}{2}}$$